# Sencha Touch: Dynamically change Stores with one List

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sencha-touch, extjs

So, I'm trying to write a little MVC application which uses lists a lot.
I have one view which consists of a Panel with Toolbar docked to top and List:

```
app.views.SalonListView = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    layout: 'card',
    cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
    dockedItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top'
        }        
    ],
    items: [
    {            
        xtype: 'SalonList',
        id: 'salon-list'
    }
    ]
});
Ext.reg('ListView', app.views.SalonListView);
```

I have an xtype for list defined in another file:

```
app.views.SalonList = Ext.extend(Ext.List, {
    layout: 'card',
    itemTpl: // some tpl is here
});
Ext.reg('SalonList', app.views.SalonList);
```

As you may notice, I don't set the Store for my List.
What am I trying to achieve is to set store in any Controller I use with this view.
Something like:

```
salonList: function() {
    app.stores.SalonStore.read();
    this.salonsView = this.render({
        xtype: 'SalonListView',
        // so I need to set store for the list somewhere around here
    });
}
```

Is there any possibility I can set the Store for the List dynamically?

Comment: Have you tried `bindStore` method?http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.DataView-method-bindStore

Comment: Well, I think it should work, but now the question is - how can I access my List from the scope of the controller?

Comment: By id, i.e. `Ext.getCmp('salon-list')`

Comment: It cannot find the List by id before it is rendered, and it cannot be rendered without a store bound to it...

Comment: then you need to avoid using lazy rendering, create the instance by using new Ext.List({})